# Determining possible rational canonical forms based on the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

It's been a while since I've studied linear algebra, so I'm hoping to refresh myself on this by going through some problems found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=yjkgNYfApj4C&pg=PA114).

I wanted to see a concrete example before attempting those to jog my memory. For instance, suppose you have a linear transformation $T$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with characteristic polynomial $\chi(X)=X^2(X^2+1)^2$. Based on $\chi(X)$, how can you figure out the possible rational canonical forms of $T$?

I tried to read up a little further on this. The eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$ and $\pm 1$ all of multiplicity 2. Does this just mean that the Jordan canonical form of $T$ as a matrix will be the matrices with diagonals of blocks

- $\text{diag}\{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} i & 1 \\ 0 & i\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -i & 1 \\ 0 & -i\end{bmatrix}\}$
- $\text{diag}\{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} i & 1 \\ 0 & i\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -i \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -i\end{bmatrix}\}$
- $\text{diag}\{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -i & 1 \\ 0 & -i\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} i \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} i\end{bmatrix}\}$
- $\vdots$
- $\text{diag}\{\begin{bmatrix} i \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} i \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -i \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -i \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}\}$

For a total of $8$ Jordan normal form decompositions. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Yes; however, your title is about *rational* canonical forms, not Jordan canonical forms. They are slightly different, though you will have the same total number. (The rational canonical form of a matrix whose characteristic polynomial splits has the same number of blocks associated to an eigenvalue as its Jordan canonical form has).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oops, I mixed them up, it's been a while since I went over them. Would the rational canonical forms just be the matrices formed by the companion matrices corresponding to the combinations $x^2$, $(x-i)^2$, $(x+i)^2$; $x^2$, $(x-i)^2$, $x+i$, $x+i$; $x^2$, $x-i$, $x-i$, $(x+i)^2$; $x$, $x$, $(x-i)^2$, $(x+i)^2$; $x^2$, $x-i$, $x-i$, $x+i$, $x+i$; $x$, $x$, $(x-i)^2$, $x+i$, $x+i$; $x$, $x$, $x-i$, $x-i$, $(x+i)^2$; $x$, $x$, $x-i$, $x-i$, $x+i$, $x+i$?

Comment: For the rational canonical form, every time you have a block of size $k$ corresponding to $\lambda$ in the Jordan canonical form, you get the companion matrix of $(x-\lambda)^k$ in the rational canonical form. So, yes.

Comment: Ah, it's coming back to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is easily reduced to the case $\chi=X^n$, that is $T$ is a nilpotent endomorphism of an $n$-dimensional vector space. Then the conjugacy classes of such endomorphisms correspond to the partitions of $n$.

**EDIT 1.** More precisely, if $m_\lambda$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a root of $\chi$, and if $p(m)$ is the number of partitions of $m$, then the number of possible conjugacy classes is the product of the $p(m_\lambda)$.

In the example, as we have three roots of multiplicity two, the number is indeed $$p(2)^3=2^3=8.$$

Two references:

- [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).
- Sequence [A000041](http://oeis.org/A000041) of [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/Seis.html).

**EDIT 2.** You can also find the number of partitions of $n$ by typing Partitions[n] on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). For instance, [Partitions[9]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+partitions+of+9) gives the number of partitions of $9$.

**EDIT 3.** One can also go to Keith Matthews's page [Computing the n-th partition number p(n)](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/partition.html), a subpage of [Number-theoretic function BCMATH programs](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/functions.html), itself a subpage of [Some BCMath/PHP number theory programs](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/php.html#functions).